# Why does the edit button sometimes appear in Settings icon?

Tags: 2013, editing-menu

We are currently fixing some migrated pages from SharePoint 2007 to 2013. For this we are editing individual pages and making changes.

One thing I have noticed here is that sometimes to edit the page I need to click on the Settings icon (gear icon) and in the menu displayed I have the "Edit Page".

[image]

Other times the "Edit" link appears outside the Settings menu.

[image]

And sometimes the "Edit" is not present at all, its only in "Settings" menu.

[image]

Why does SharePoint show the "Edit" link at two different places?

Answer (score 1):

Convenience? This has been the case for a long time, they surface the same options in multiple places. The cog is the new site actions where this has always been an option, and the other link functions like the ribbon where this option exists.

Comment: There are sometimes when the "Edit" is present in "Settings" menu and is not present in the top bar (I hope thats what it is called). I updated my question with the screenshot to describe this scenario. This actually confuses to no end!

Comment: Is that a document library? it wouldn't make sense to have Edit available in a document library so it isn't present there.

Comment: I think you might be onto something here. For pages in "Pages" library I see "Edit" and "Settings > Edit" menu while for "SitePages" I see only "Settings > Edit". Is that the reason?

Comment: Probably, the menus are contextual, so if in a library, you are only going to see edit page in the cog. if you are on a web part page, you'll see edit page in the bar there as well as in the cog.